# how to write large [ include 2 { like this picture

Tags: delimiters

Please teach me. how to write large [ include 2 { like this picture.

I can't do it. Please help me.

That's my code

```
\left[
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{rl}
0<\dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}}<1\\
\sqrt{4y^2-1}>\dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{array} \right.\\
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{rl}
\dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}}>1\\
\sqrt{4y^2-1}<\dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{array} \right. \right.
\Rightarrow
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify the left-most delimiter?  Is it desired to be a bracket `[` (as in the question title) or a `\ceil` (as in the included figure)?  Furthermore, do you wish it thick as shown, or not so thick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this, where I replicate the `cases` environment with a different delimiter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{lceilcases}
 {\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lceil
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}}
 {\endarray\right.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{lceilcases}
  \begin{dcases}
  0 < \frac{2y}{\sqrt{3}} < 1\\
  \sqrt{4y^2-1} > \frac{2y}{\sqrt{3}}
  \end{dcases}
\\ \\
  \begin{dcases}
  \frac{2y}{\sqrt{3}} > 1\\
  \sqrt{4y^2-1} < \frac{2y}{\sqrt{3}}
  \end{dcases}
\end{lceilcases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution woudl be to use the `amsmath` `aligned`-environment:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left[
    \begin{aligned}
      \begin{cases}
        \dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}} > 1\\
        \sqrt{4y^2 - 1} < \dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}}
      \end{cases}
      \\
      \begin{cases}
        0 < \dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}} < 1\\
        \sqrt{4y^2 - 1} > \dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}}
      \end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the left delimiter is supposed to be a `\lceil` rather than a `[`, a simple substitution may be made in the MWE, from `\left[` to `\left\lceil`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\def\stackalignment{l}
\left[%
\stackanchor{
\begin{cases}
0 < \dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}} < 1\\
\sqrt{4y^2 - 1} > \dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{cases}
}{
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}} > 1\\
\sqrt{4y^2 - 1} < \dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{cases}
}\right.\Rightarrow
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]